# while loop - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

Maybe it's too simple and I just didn't see my mistake.

```
while list_a[y] in list_a != list_a[-1]:
    print(y);y=y+1
```

returns `IndexError: list index out of range`

`list_a` looks like:

```
['00001', '00001', '00002', '00009', '0000G', '0000K', '0000K', '0000U', '0000U', '00013', '0001B', '0001D', '0001D', '0001L', '0001L', '0001N', '0001Q', '0001Q', '0001R', '0001U']
```

and my aim in the end is to delete some items from the list while iterating (that's why I want to use a `while` loop instead of `for y in range(len(list_a))`).

Comment: What do you think this condition does? It tests whether `list_a[y]` is in `list_a` (either true or indexerror) and then compares that (true) to `list_a[-1]`. Probably not what you wanted. Have you tried just using `while y < len(list_a)`?

Comment: in the end the loop does <something> until the last entry of the list everything correctly. Then it compares again and the error occurs

Comment: (Minor correction: `in` and `!=` have the same [precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), so `x in y != z` actually evaluates like `(x in y) and (y != z)`, similar to `x < y < z`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think what you were trying for was:

```
while list_a[y] != list_a[-1]:
    ...
```

i.e. "while we're looking at the item that isn't equal to the last in the list". However, there will still be issues; what if items appear elsewhere in the list that are equal to the last item?

The general way to do this is to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build a new list from the appropriate items in the old list:

```
list_b = [item for item in list_a if some_test(item)]
```